# How to pass this code to codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I would like to pass this code to CodeIgniter, but I don't know how. I'm starting with CI and starting with Json. How can I do that? Please, help me lol

```
 $base= mysqli_connect($dbhost,  $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbbase);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    $return_arr = array();

    if ($result = mysqli_query( $base, $sql )){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['col1'] = $row['col1'];
        $row_array['col2'] = $row['col2'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
       }
     }

    mysqli_close($base);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

And how i get this with jquery/json, I was looking for something and I found this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var id = <?= $val->id; ?>;

        $.ajax({
            url: "page.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (JSONObject) {    
                for (var key in JSONObject) {
                    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        alert(JSONObject[key]["name"]);
                    }
                }

            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Thank right now

Comment: You want to change the above code to codeigniter format or something?

Comment: @AlexandreXavier What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Yes Amith, i'm trying to change code to codeigniter format

Comment: RiaanV i'm trying to get result of the DB and show the view using json

Comment: I need pass to the view in array, but i dont know how using CI and Json

Comment: What is the `$sql` query you need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has its own database library, which you can use. I find it much simpler than the PHP mysqli functions, and highly recommend it.

First, in application/config/database.php, you will define the host, username, password, and database name as you do in the initial mysqli_connect command.

Second, you must load the database library. You can do this by:

```
$this->load->library('database')
```

Or by including in the config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Once loaded, you can access the database library. Then you can run a query with:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

(from [CI's site](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html))

Though, I recommend you also learn about the [Query Builder Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) codeigniter offers. In my experience it can make building complex, dynamic SQL queries server side quite easy.

With regards to getting it with JQuery ajax - the basic structure you have is right. Of course, you need to make sure the url is configured correctly, have your script configured to do something with the ID you're passing, etc, but it's the proper base format.